# Exclude null GenericForeignKey objects from Django query

Tags: django, django-models, generic-foreign-key

I have an `ActivityLog` Django Model that defines a generic foreign key with the following fields:

```
model_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_("Object type"))
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Object id"))
object = generic.GenericForeignKey('model_type', 'object_id')
```

I need to filter the `ActivityLog` instances whose related `object` has not been deleted (is not None). Django doesn't do an on delete cascade in `GenericForeignKey` and I need to exclude this undesired records from the lookup. Is there an easy, standard and efficient way to do this?

In a wonderful world I'd use something like:

```
real_activity_logs = ActivityLog.objects.filter(object__isnull=False)
```

But this doesn't work as `object` is not a database field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those `ActivityLog` instances to be deleted in a cascade, you can make that happen by defining a `GenericRelation` on the objects pointed to. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations):

> Note also, that if you delete an object that has a GenericRelation, any objects which have
>   a GenericForeignKey pointing at it will be deleted as well.

Comment: After posting this question to SO and after more deep research and testing I found exactly the answer you give as the right way to go. Two points to note: 1) If the model containing the `GenericForeignKey` is referenced by the pointed model through a normal `ForeignKey`, you must set a `related_name` in the `GenericForeignKey` or disable it with `'+'`. 2) You can define the `GenericRelation` within abstract Models, there is no problem, as opposite to defining relations (in that cases you must set `related_name` properly as explained in the docs). Thanks!

Comment: @Caumons Glad to hear it, thanks for the extra clarification.